# GoJS - Click event strange behaviour, "this" ends up being null

Tags: events, click, gojs

I would like to update some list panels when my GoJS diagram is clicked. The click event fires everytime, but sometimes `this` ends up being `null` within the event, and I can't access the rest of my panel. Any ideas why this might be?

```
myDiagram.linkTemplate =
    $(Link,
    $(Shape,
        { strokeWidth: 1, stroke: "gray" },
    $(Shape, new Binding("fromArrow", "fa")),
    $(Shape, new Binding("toArrow", "ta")),
    {
        click: (e: go.InputEvent, obj: go.GraphObject, ) => {
            console.log('[nav123] starting click');
            this.listPanelA.scrollToRow(obj['pb'].rowNumber);
            this.listPanelB.scrollToRow(obj['pb'].rowNumber);
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `e` and `obj` arguments instead of `this`, which is difficult to predict in JavaScript, because you do not know the context that calls the event.

Comment: Thanks, I used the GraphObject to find my list panels.

Comment: A little update on this..

I managed to get around this issue by adding following to the parent function that contains the event definition:
`let me = this;`